# getopt_long() function does not update option_index variable

Tags: c, getopt-long

kindly help. 
I've gone all over online manuals... yet, no hint whats wrong.

The problem is that **option_index** does not get updated by **getopt_long()**, thus I'm unable to access proper struct members in form of **long_options[option_index].name** etc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int opt=0;
    int option_index=0;
    struct option long_options[]={
        {"first",   required_argument,  NULL,   'f'},
        {"second",  no_argument,        NULL,   's'},
        {"third",   required_argument,  NULL,   't'},
        {NULL,      0,                  NULL,   0}
    };

    while (1){
        option_index=0;
        opt=getopt_long (argc,argv, "f:st:", long_options, &option_index);
        if ( opt == -1 )
            break;

        printf("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
        if (optarg)
            printf(" with arg %s", optarg);
        printf("\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output :

```
# ~/workspace/Test/Debug/Test -f 1 -s -t third
option first with arg 1
option first
option first with arg third
```

- Verified with debugger that option_index left unchanged during entire execution.

Thanks in advance, any idea / lead will be appreciated !

Comment: try `Test --first 1 --second --third third`

Comment: That did the magic - thanks a lot, but now I'm confused - no way to get option_index when short option supplied ?
* My program relies on checking if identified option expect optarg,
I've counted on getting this from long_options[option_index].has_arg

Comment: It is not used when you specify the short option. it can be tested in `if(long_options[option_index].flag == 0)` If the long option is used.

Comment: If not much trouble :
1. Can you share link to source of this explanation (maybe I've missed something else )
2. Any suggestion for work around in case short option supplied to know if corresponding long_option expects argument ? ( in my case I do not use flags, all zeroes )
Thank you.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html#Getopt-Long-Options

Comment: Programmer knows a string of long option that corresponds to the short option.

Comment: _in my case I do not use flags, all zeroes_ : It is a different story.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY - Thanks for good will, effort and lead. I'll update here if will find any work around in described constrains.